# Updating a row works when I use a string but not when Integer

Tags: c#, sql, oledb

I am updating a access database using data taken from Textboxes. If I clear a textbox that takes a string the update works fine, but if I clear a textbox that takes an Integer I get this error message

> Failed to convert parameter value from a String to a Int32

This is my code:

```
 cmd.Parameters.Add("@inOrOut", OleDbType.VarWChar).Value = tbPatientStatus.Text;
 cmd.Parameters.Add("@BedID", OleDbType.Integer).Value = tbPatientBedID.Text;
```

From comments below I have tried this with no success

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(tbPatientBedID.Text))
{
  cmd.Parameters.Add("@BedID", OleDbType.Integer).Value = 0;
}
else
{
  cmd.Parameters.Add("@BedID", OleDbType.Integer).Value = tbPatientBedID.Text;
}
```

Comment: if db variable is of type int, then convert the value to int before passing

Comment: It works fine if I enter an integer its only when I leave the textbox empty I get the error

Comment: What value are you expecting the integer to have if left empty?

Comment: Its going into a database so I suppose null?

Comment: That would depend on the query. Patientstatus if left empty will have the value `''` (empty string), not null. There is no such thing as an empty integer though.

Comment: How to I change the empty string to something the database would accept e.g. null or 0. Maybe surround the statement in an if statement checking the value is not an empty string and inserting a different value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Small example using tryparse to get the int value.

```
        int value;
        if !(int.TryParse(tbPatientBedID.Text, out value))
            value = 0;

        cmd.Parameters.Add("@BedID", OleDbType.Integer).Value = value;
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your answer at all.

Comment: the string.Concat just concatenates the commandtext with the result of the  evaluated text. You could just do `if(!int.TryParse(text, out value)) value = 0` meaning that if the text does not evaluate to an int then assign zero, else the parsed value is used.

Comment: Can you please explain how this post can be a answer to this question?

Comment: I don't know how to implement it in my program

Comment: Copy an paste my answer into your code in place of your original statement

Comment: @JerryMurphy checked this with this code and the solution above is evaluating 'OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("UPDATE TABLE SET column = ?"); cmd.Parameters.Add("@BedID", OleDbType.Integer).Value = value;'

Comment: Success!!! From all the copying and pasting of peoples solution I had an extra line of cmd.Parameters.Add("@BedID but when I removed that your solution works. Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

```
  int? BedId = null;
  int m_BedID = 0;
  if(Int32.TryParse(tbPatientBedID.Text.Trim(), out m_BedID))
  {
     BedId = m_BedID;
  }      

  cmd.Parameters.Add("@inOrOut", OleDbType.VarWChar).Value = tbPatientStatus.Text;
  cmd.Parameters.Add("@BedID", OleDbType.Integer).Value = BedID;
```

When you adding parameter type `OleDbType.Integer` provided value type should be `integer` too..

Comment: That gives a different error - "Input string was not in a correct format"

Comment: You need to check that the text can be parsed to an int, see the example I posted.

Comment: @Moumit TryParse is going to lead to fewer operations. The Trim() operations are not required.

Comment: Says there is no implicit conversion between System.DBNull and int

Comment: Sorry @JerryMurphy .. i should have checked the syntax .. now i checked .. :)

Comment: I tried it, new error message - "Failed to convert parameter value from a String to a Int32."

Comment: @JerryMurphy .. check pls.. :)

Comment: this line gives me an error- Int32.TryParse(tbPatientBedID.Text.Trim(), out BedID); --BedID is underlined and the error is -cannot convert from 'out int? to 'out int'

Comment: BedID is a nullable int, remove the question mark so it's not nullable.